# Display exact scala command issued from SBT build

Tags: sbt, scalac

When I build my (relatively complex) SBT project against a local version of Scala, I am getting the following error:

```
scalac error: bad option: '-Ydelambdafy:method'
```

This is potentially a bug in `scalac` or our buildfile. However, I am unable to reproduce this error while invoking `scalac` directly:

```
$ scalac -Ydelambdafy:method test.scala
```

This runs as expected. Is there a way I can make SBT display the exact `scalac` command it issues? (Note that passing the exact flags from `scalacOptions` to `scalac` also does not result in the error).

`scalacOptions` is:

```
List(
  -deprecation,
  -unchecked,
  -feature,
  -encoding, utf8,
  -Ydelambdafy:method,
  -Xplugin:<...>/scala-js-test/compiler/target/scala-2.11.0-RC1/scalajs-compiler_2.11.0-RC1-0.4.1-SNAPSHOT.jar)`
)
```

The repository in question is the `scalajs-library` subproject of the [Scala.js master](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js) with a build of the current [Scala master](https://github.com/scala/scala) as `scalaHome`.

To configure the project for this build, issue:

```
set every List(scalaHome := Some(file("<scalaHome>")), scalaVersion := "2.11.0-RC1")
```

in the root project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here's the thing: sbt doesn't actually call "scalac". It invokes the compiler directly, creating and calling the proper class.

However, if you are using SBT 0.13+, you can get an approximation of what it *would* have run if it did run it directly, but doing this:

```
export compile
```

The `export` command also work for some other tasks, but not, by any means, all of them.

Comment: I knew something better existed that my answer with `debug` and `compile`, but forgot about it as I'm not using it often. Thanks for bringing it up!

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is `debug` and then `compile`.

```
[sbt-0-13-2]> help debug
debug

    Sets the global logging level to debug.
    This will be used as the default level for logging from commands, settings, and tasks.
    Any explicit `logLevel` configuration in a project overrides this setting.

--debug

    Sets the global logging level as described above, but does so before any other commands are executed on startup, including project loading.
    This is useful as a startup option:
        * it takes effect before any logging occurs
        * if no other commands are passed, interactive mode is still entered

[sbt-0-13-2]> debug
[debug] > shell
[sbt-0-13-2]> compile
[debug] > compile
[debug] Evaluating tasks: compile:compile
[debug] Running task... Cancelable: false, check cycles: false
...
[debug] Running cached compiler 3d61bf70, interfacing (CompilerInterface) with Scala compiler version 2.10.4-RC1
[debug] Calling Scala compiler with arguments  (CompilerInterface):
[debug]     -bootclasspath
[debug]     /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/classes:/Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.10.4-RC1.jar
[debug]     -classpath
[debug]     /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.2/target/scala-2.10/classes
[debug] Scala compilation took 77.142708 s
```

Comment: Or simply using `last`: it will show the debug output of the previous command.