# Trouble compiling Scala project on command line

Tags: scala

I have a Scala project with several Scala files as well as a `lib` directory with some pre-compiled JAR dependencies. My project directory structure looks something like this:

```
project/src/main/scala/com/example/app/main.scala
project/src/main/scala/com/example/app/class1.scala
project/src/main/scala/com/example/app/class2.scala
project/lib/dependency1.jar
project/lib/dependency2.jar
```

where `main.scala` is a Scala Object with a main method that calls classes in `class1.scala` and `class2.scala`. My actual file structure has many more classes and libraries than this simple example. I'd like to output my compiled classes to a folder, `root/compiled_classes`.

I try to compile on the command line like so

```
> scalac -classpath "lib/*" -d compiled_classes src/main/scala/com/example/app/*
```

I receive errors indicating that my library dependencies are not being properly understood...something like

```
src\main\scala\com\example\app\class1.scala:32: error: not found: type Model
    var model: Model = new LinkedHashModel()
```

where `Model` is a class imported from one of the dependency files. All in all, I get 476 of these errors, seeming to be every time I call a class imported from a dependency.

If it makes a difference, these `.jar` files were downloaded by SBT and originally stored in my `home/.ivy2` folder, from which I copied them into the `project/lib` folder. Perhaps this isn't the optimal way of managing JARs, but I thought that it should work.

I'm also open to other suggestions if there is a better way to compile an entire Scala project via the command line.

EDIT

Ran compilation in verbose mode. Here is the beginning and end of the output

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\resources.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jsse.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jce.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\charsets.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jfr.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\jline-2.14.1.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-compiler.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.0.4.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-reflect.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-swing_2.12-2.0.0-M2.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-xml_2.12-1.0.6.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scalap-2.12.1.jar is not yet in the classpath cache
[search path for source files: ]
[search path for class files: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\jline-2.14.1.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-compiler.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.0.4.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-reflect.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-swing_2.12-2.0.0-M2.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-xml_2.12-1.0.6.jar;C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scalap-2.12.1.jar]
[loaded package loader <root package> in 180ms]
[loaded package loader java in 2ms]
[loaded package loader java.lang in 25ms]
[loaded package loader scala.annotation in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/reflect/package.class) in 39ms]
[loaded package loader scala.reflect in 47ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/package.class) in 60ms]
[loaded package loader scala in 89ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/CloneNotSupportedException.class) in 3ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/InterruptedException.class) in 1ms]
[loaded package loader java.io in 5ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/Throwable.class) in 18ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/Object.class) in 256ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/runtime/package.class) in 2ms]
[loaded package loader scala.runtime in 9ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/collection/package.class) in 3ms]
[loaded package loader scala.collection in 10ms]
[loaded package loader java.util in 11ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/UnsupportedEncodingException.class) in 1ms]
[loaded package loader java.nio in 3ms]
[loaded package loader java.nio.charset in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/String.class) in 36ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/Comparable.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/Serializable.class) in 1ms]
[promote the dependency of lambdalift: erasure => posterasure]
```

...

```
src\main\scala\com\example\app\class1.scala:325: error: not found: type RepositoryConnection
    def retrieveBMIData (cxn: RepositoryConnection): ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Value]] =
                              ^
src\main\scala\com\example\app\class1.scala:32: error: not found: type Model
        var model: Model = new LinkedHashModel()
                   ^
src\main\scala\com\example\app\class1.scala:32: error: not found: type LinkedHashModel
        var model: Model = new LinkedHashModel()
                               ^
src\main\scala\com\example\app\class1.scala:298: error: not found: type Value
    def handleMultipleBMIRecordingsForSingleEncounter(result: ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Value]], a: Int, f: ValueFactory): Array[Object] =
                                                                                      ^
src\main\scala\com\example\app\class1.scala:298: error: not found: type ValueFactory
    def handleMultipleBMIRecordingsForSingleEncounter(result: ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[Value]], a: Int, f: ValueFactory): Array[Object] =
                                                                                                          ^
src\main\scala\com\example\app\class1.scala:189: error: not found: type Model
    def addBMIInconclusion(model: Model, encounter: Value, explanation: String, f: ValueFactory): Model =
                                                                                                  ^
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/collection/generic/MutableMapFactory.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/collection/generic/MapFactory.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/collection/generic/GenMapFactory.class) in 5ms]
[loaded package loader java.nio.channels in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/IOException.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/System.class) in 8ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/unchecked.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/noinline.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/inline.class) in 0ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/collection/immutable/NumericRange.class) in 2ms]
[loaded module class loader in 5ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/collection/immutable/Range.class) in 3ms]
[loaded module class loader in 4ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/reflect/macros/internal/macroImpl.class) in 4ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/collection/parallel/immutable/ParRange.class) in 4ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/annotation/unchecked/uncheckedVariance.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/annotation/TypeConstraint.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/FileNotFoundException.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/FileInputStream.class) in 3ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/InputStream.class) in 3ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/Closeable.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/AutoCloseable.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/SyncFailedException.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/FileDescriptor.class) in 4ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/net/MalformedURLException.class) in 1ms]
[loaded package loader java.nio.file in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/File.class) in 9ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/util/InvalidPropertiesFormatException.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/util/Properties.class) in 8ms]
[loaded package loader java.util.function in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/util/Map.class) in 7ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/util/Hashtable.class) in 17ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/util/Dictionary.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/Reader.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/Readable.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/NullPointerException.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/net/URISyntaxException.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/net/URI.class) in 6ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/PrintWriter.class) in 9ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/Writer.class) in 3ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/Appendable.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/Flushable.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/OutputStream.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/Function3.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/util/UUID.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/nio/file/WatchEvent.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/nio/file/Path.class) in 11ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/nio/file/Paths.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/BufferedReader.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/FileReader.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/InputStreamReader.class) in 5ms]
[loaded package loader sun.util in 1ms]
[loaded package loader sun.util.locale in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/util/MissingResourceException.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/util/Locale.class) in 25ms]
[loaded package loader java.text in 1ms]
[loaded package loader java.time in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/util/Calendar.class) in 6ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/util/TimeZone.class) in 3ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/text/SimpleDateFormat.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/text/ParseException.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/text/DateFormat.class) in 4ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/text/AttributedCharacterIterator.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/text/Format.class) in 8ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/text/DateFormatSymbols.class) in 5ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/util/Date.class) in 5ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/StringBuffer.class) in 6ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/text/FieldPosition.class) in 3ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/FileWriter.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/OutputStreamWriter.class) in 5ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/net/URL.class) in 3ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/net/URLStreamHandler.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/net/ConnectException.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/net/SocketException.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/nio/charset/CharacterCodingException.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.class) in 4ms]
[loaded package loader java.nio.charset.spi in 0ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/nio/charset/Charset.class) in 5ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/BufferedInputStream.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/io/FilterInputStream.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/security/NoSuchAlgorithmException.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/security/NoSuchProviderException.class) in 2ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/security/DigestException.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/security/MessageDigest.class) in 22ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/security/Provider.class) in 5ms]
[loaded class file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/security/MessageDigestSpi.class) in 1ms]
[loaded class file C:\PROGRA~2\scala\bin\..\lib\scala-library.jar(scala/Function2.class) in 2ms]
[typer in 6508ms]
[total in 7299ms]
476 errors found
```

Comment: Have you considered using [sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/)? (it has a command line interface... does it have a non-command-line one?)

Comment: I do use SBT for the most part, however for my current task it is a requirement that the project be compiled and run from the command line.

Comment: Is it possible that any of the `.jar` files in `lib/` have dependencies of their own that are missing?

Comment: I copied every `.jar` file from my `.ivy2` directory, which was populated by SBT. If it runs in SBT, shouldn't it also run via command line?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin yes, SBT has a command line interface, but I need to be able to run directly from a Windows shell...I think it should be possible

Comment: @hayfreed I've never used it, but maybe sbt [export compile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22418750/2707792) might help? (I'm currently struggling to make it produce any useful output, but maybe it's just me...)

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys...I was able to get this to work using SBT Assembly (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly). Still curious as to why I was not able to do it from command line though...